# PyPDF2 Module and Encryted PDF Files

Tags: pypdf

I'm currently using PyPDF2 to work with PDF files in Python.

When I run a script to load some PDF files and extract some key words from the PDFs, I'm not able to:

```
PdfReadError: File has not been decrypted
```

So to (try &) get around this I implement:

```
if pathObj.isEncrypted:
        pathObj.decrypt('')
```

However, I'm then comfronted with:

```
NotImplementedError: only algorithm code 1 and 2 are supported
```

Now, I kinda understand what the errors are telling me. What I don't understand is the fact that *none of my PDFs are encrypted*

Does anyone know why files that are not encryted *are apparently* encrypted? Is this some issue with PyPDF2?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that these PDFs are 128-bit AES type encrypted. However, they can still used in Adobe just not with PyPDF2.

To get around the problem you have to install:

```
qpdf
```

and add to the code:

```
qpdf, --password=" ", --decrypt, in_put.pdf, out_put.pdf
```